# Kestrel HTTPS Present Certificate Chain

Tags: c#, .net, https, kestrel

I'm building a web service using a custom (trusted) cert chain with no intermediate CAs, and when I terminate SSL with Kestrel, it only presents my server cert:

[image]

If I go to any site on the net, I see the whole cert chain:
[image]

How do I make Kestrel present the entire cert chain?  If I go to google.com